# window location problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Trying to do a simple search via id:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(window).load(function(){
        $("#submit").click(function() {
            var s = $("#search").val();
            var url = "/tags/" + s;

            if(s == empty) {
                $("#search").attr("placeholder", "הכנס תוכן לחיפוש").placeholder();
            }else{
                window.location.replace(url);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

I want to make a windows location if the input not empty, and if the input is empty then change the place holder.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="search-box">
    <input type="text" name='sec' id='search' placeholder="חפש במאמרים">
    <input type="submit" value="" id='submit'>
</div>
```

Comment: Describe the problem? Most likely you need `event.preventDefault()` or change submit type to button.

Comment: Its just do nothing.. i tried to change to button and still no succes..

Comment: What were you hoping `.placeholder()` was going to do?

Comment: change the current place holder.... beacus i dont want to do an empty search..

Comment: And how about `== empty`. Where is the `empty` variable coming from? I think you're making guesses at how to do stuff by putting random syntax in place. Checking for an empty string can be done like this:  `s == ""`, and there is no `.placeholder()` method on a strings. Open your developer console to see errors.

Comment: yeah i wasnt sure about the placeholder beacuse of the attr.

Comment: thank you anyway my problem was on the empty i put instead NULL

Comment: i Still dont get a redirect from my windows location replace... someone know where the bug came from?

Comment: @squint, .placeholder() is a jquery plugin: https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're comparing `s` with the variable `empty` which is not defined... Instead try this:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(window).load(function(){
        $("#submit").click(function() {
            var s = $("#search").val();
            if (s != '') {
               location.replace('http://test.com/tags/' + s);
            } else {
              $("#search").attr("placeholder", "הכנס תוכן לחיפוש").placeholder();
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: still have a bug with the windows location

Comment: זה לא מעביר לעמוד שאני רושם לו, כאילו הוא מעביר למיקום אחר

Comment: האמת שלא גבר אבל הוא פשוט לא מעביר את העמוד כמו שצריך כי בדקתי גם כאשר הצבתי את הפלט בדיב הוא הציג קישור תקין.

Comment: test.com/tags/{הפלט של החיפוש מאינפוט #SEARCH}

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 });
```

placeholder :
    Automatic after keyup => show

not jquery code necessary

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: doument is not defined
ERROR :/

Comment: if you want give me teamviewer